# scrapyd shared middleware and pipeline code

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have several scrapy projects that I have deployed to a scrapyd instance. They all tend to use the same middleware code that I have created and that I have duplicated amongst the projects.

I would like to avoid this duplication of code. Is there a way for scrapy projects deployed on scrapyd to share the same middleware code without resorting to combining all projects into the one project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible if you create a package of your middleware and call it within your settings.py
a good example of it (and one I use often) is for instance : https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/scrapy-useragents
hope it helps